# How can I upload a GIF image via imagePicker to Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to allow users of my app to upload GIFs.

I'm using `info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.referenceURL] as! NSURL` to get the temp location of the selected GIF.

I get this error when I try to use this URL info to upload to Firebase:

```
error uploading to firebase
File at URL: assets-library://asset/asset.GIF?id=6140CE69-7678-4668-BC55-EB6CF6D975CF&ext=GIF is not reachable. Ensure file URL is not a directory, symbolic link, or invalid url.
```

This is a code snippet of how I'm trying to upload:

```
let imageName = UUID().uuidString
let storage = Storage.storage()
if (imagePath.hasSuffix("GIF")) {
    let storingimage = storage.reference().child("\(imageName).gif")

    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/gif"


    storingimage.putFile(from: URL(string: imagePath)!, metadata: metadata)
```

I'm using this method because swift does not provide a `jpegData()` or `pngData()` equivalent for gif images.

Can anyone share how to get around this error and save a GIF image to firebase?

I have also tried to use `putData()` to no success

```
let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: imagePath)!)
storingimage.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata)

Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “asset.GIF” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=assets-library://asset/asset.GIF?id=6140CE69-7678-4668-BC55-EB6CF6D975CF&ext=GIF}
```

and `fileURLWithPath` variety

```
let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath))
storingimage.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata)

Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “asset.GIF?id=6140CE69-7678-4668-BC55-EB6CF6D975CF&ext=GIF” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/assets-library:/asset/asset.GIF?id=6140CE69-7678-4668-BC55-EB6CF6D975CF&ext=GIF,
```

Comment: The code in the question is quite choppy and incomplete so it's hard to know what's going on. Take a look a the Firebase Getting Started Guide for storage [Upload from a local file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file) as that code works almost off the shelf. The type of file, gif, jpg etc is not important as Storage will hold any file type. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I think you are getting the URL of a URL which may be the actual issue.